# Javascript confirm makes Safari freeze with HTML from remote server

Tags: javascript, safari, confirm

Safari does not show a `confirm` window with code served from a remote host. After `onclick` Safari freezes without any message in the javascript console. The same code does work when it is served from a local host and the code works in Chrome, whether served from remote host or local host.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    confirm("Press a button!");
}
</script>
```

Version: Safari version 12.0.1, MacOS Mojave version 10.14.1

Comment: what the actual f

Comment: @GottZ what do you mean with "what the actual f"?

Comment: Very strange: the HTML confirm example served from w3schools.com (remote host) does work in the Safari browser, but the same code served from my remote host does not work. I inspected the source code from within the browser and the simple code snippet are identical..

Comment: by „what the actual f“ i mean: how could apple screw this up again. i quit using macos in july for stability and bad experience reasons. now i see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up **restarting** my MacBook (which I rarely do) and guess what...problem solved. The HTML `confirm` in Safari is not a problem anymore.

I did not change any code on my remote host in the meanwhile. And it really surprises me that the HTML/Javascript code from one remote host (w3schools) works and the same code served from the other remote host (my remote host) does not work. After the restart of my computer (not just the browser) the confirm popup works like it did before.

I don't exactly know when I last updated the MacBook due to auto-update preferences. I guess restarting the computer from time to time isn't that bad.